# Call a storyboard declared in xaml from c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I am trying to call a storyboard declared in xaml from c#.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="PlayStoryboard" x:Key="PlayAnimation">
        ...
```

I dont have access to "PlayStoryboard" from the codebehind file. Any ideas what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Since you declared your Storyboard as a Resource, you can access it by using FindResource("PlayAnimation").  See sample below:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="PlayAnimation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)">
            <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:1"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Canvas>
        <Button x:Name="btn">Test</Button>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Storyboard sb = this.FindResource("PlayAnimation") as Storyboard;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(sb, this.btn);
        sb.Begin();
    }
}
```

Comment: be sure to have "using System.Windows.Media.Animation;" in place.

Comment: Is there a way to find a resource loaded dynamically?