# How to animate image in splash screen for windows phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am working on windows phone app in which I need to animate an object in the splash screen. In the below image you can see that, as soon as the splash screen appears. The ball.png bounces and only after completing the bounce, the app continues into the application.  How to do this task?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You have to follow thoses steps to create an animated splashscreen :

- You have to create a new Page on your application (called
  SplashScreen.xaml) and set it as your 'HomePage'.
- You [create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755651/call-a-storyboard-declared-in-xaml-from-c-sharp) a storyboard to build your animation.
- You subscribe to the Loaded event of the SplashScreen page, and [start your
  storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755651/call-a-storyboard-declared-in-xaml-from-c-sharp).
- When the storyboard is done (subscribe to the Completed event), you can navigate to your
  Homepage.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Short, sweet and simple explanation. +1

Answer (score 1):

Use `Extended Splash Screen` and set the animation to the image. For more details [visit here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Splash_Screen_and_Extended_Splash_Screen_wp8).

Comment: Link explains how to add simple image... but really helpful for those who only want to add static images... +1