# WPF - Cant Find Storyboard in C#

Tags: wpf

I have created Storyboard in WPF (in Objects and Timeline tab) for my grid element however when I go to C#, intelicence only shows my targeted element and no Storyboard name in this element or outside of it.

How can I access my storyboard in C#? Where is it? I want it to start playing using C# but I cant find it any where.

Comment: You need to declare a `Storyboard` as a resource, and using the `FindResource()` to find it. Examples: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755651/call-a-storyboard-declared-in-xaml-from-c-sharp) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fbf9c605-1db1-4017-8847-8e01f89239d0/how-can-i-pause-a-wpf-storyboard-using-c-code-behind?forum=blend).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<Window.Resources>
<Storyboard x:Key="StoryboardName">
    <DoubleAnimation></DoubleAnimation>
</Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
```

and in behind code

```
 Storyboard StoryboardName = this.Resources["StoryboardName"] as Storyboard;
```

and use this StoryboardName name for animation