# wpf Storyboard Trigger in C#

Tags: wpf

I have an animation with this trigger setup in LoadingAnimation.xaml:

```
<UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="ProgressAnimation_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource ProgressAnimation}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

In my MainWindow.xaml, I have this inside a grid:

```
<control:LoadingAnimation x:Name="loadingAnimation" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

I understand that I can start the storyboard with the following code:

```
Storyboard storyboard = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("ProgressAnimation") as Storyboard;
storyboard.Begin();
```

But how can I use "FindResource() when my storyboard is in a different class?

Comment: related post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755651/call-a-storyboard-declared-in-xaml-from-c-sharp

Comment: Where is your `Storyboard` declaration?

Comment: It's inside LoadingAnimation:
<UserControl.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="ProgressAnimation" RepeatBehavior="Forever">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out.
First I needed to define the loadingAnimation user control as a resource to be able to use the method FindResource().
Then after finding the resource, I needed to call FindResource() again to get the storyboard, since it was defined as a resource within loadingAnimation.

This was in my  tag:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <control:LoadingAnimation x:Key="loadingAnimation" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and then to use it in the grid, I put this line of code in the  tag:

```
<UserControl Content="{StaticResource loadingAnimation}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
```

Then in C# I used this method to get access to the Storyboard:

```
private void beginStoryBoard()
        {
            UserControl loadingAnimation = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("loadingAnimation") as UserControl;
            Storyboard storyboard = loadingAnimation.FindResource("ProgressAnimation") as Storyboard;
            storyboard.Begin();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lot many questions asking for this,

```
<Window.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/AssembelyName;component/LoadingAnimation.xaml"/> 
     </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
   </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

Storyboard storyboard = this.FindResource("ProgressAnimation") as Storyboard;// this - is the current window's instance
storyboard.Begin();
```

get your Storyboard and call the begin method.

Comment: the xaml code with the storyboard is in a different class to the MainWindow.xaml/cs class. How can I find a resource in a different class?

Comment: MainWindow.cs/xaml is in the root namespace, then in a subnamespace, I have the storyboard. How can I access it?
The code you provided doesn't work. It says it cannot be found.

Comment: Basically the LoadingAnimation class has the ProgressAnimation storyboard. 
So not sure how to start the storyboard, using the:
<control:LoadingAnimation x:Name="loadingAnimation" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

Comment: Check the updated answer, by merging the resource file you can get the  storyboard and you can start the storyboard there..

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.ResourceReferenceKeyNotFoundException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'ProgressAnimation' resource not found.

Comment: ok I FindResource() works coz I wrote this:
<Window.Resources>
        <control:LoadingAnimation x:Key="loadingAnimation" x:Name="loadingAnimation" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    </Window.Resources>

But it won't show up on the grid anymore.